# From a Popup I need to enter to an external function from my kv kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Good day everyone! I created a function and this is located on my screen "Contact" called "resetcampos" in my main.py, then I created a Popup in my kv.file. I need to access my function "resetcampos" from my Button that I have in the Popup. what should I write where it's written "on_press: -----" for accesing to my function "resetcampos" that is in my main.py?

py.main

```
from tokenize import Number
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import smtplib

Config.set('graphics', 'width', 360)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 640)
kv= Builder.load_file('test6.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
    def spinner_clicked(self,value):
        pass
        #sm= ScreenManager()
        #screen= Screen(name='second')
        #self.ids.Label1.text= f'You selected: {value}'

#Define a RecycleView

class RV (Screen):
    pass



#Definine our different screens
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    #Variables Shopping Cart
    var1= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart.png")
    var2= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart2.png")
    

    #Functions Items
    def list_tornillo(self):      
        tornillo= self.ids.input_tornillo.text
        #tornillo1= str(float(tornillo) * 0.1) if tornillo else "0.0"
        tornillo1= str(round(float(tornillo) * 0.1,2)) if tornillo else "0.0"
        tornillo2= tornillo1 + "0"  
        self.ids.label_tornillo.text= tornillo2

    
    def list_andamio(self):  
        andamio= self.ids.input_andamio.text
        andamiod= andamio.isdigit()
        if andamiod == True:             
            andamio1= str(round(float(andamio) * 180,2)) if andamio else "0.0"
            andamio2= andamio1 + "0"  
            self.ids.label_andamio.text= andamio2
        else: 
            self.ids.input_andamio.text= "0"
            
             
    def list_vigueta(self):      
        vigueta= self.ids.input_vigueta.text
        vigueta1= str(round(float(vigueta) * 200,2)) if vigueta else "0.0"
        vigueta2= vigueta1 + "0"  
        self.ids.label_vigueta.text= vigueta2

    def list_perno(self):      
        perno= self.ids.input_perno.text
        perno1= str(round(float(perno) * 0.20,2)) if perno else "0.0"
        perno2= perno1 + "0"  
        self.ids.label_perno.text= perno2

    def list_tuerca(self):      
        tuerca= self.ids.input_tuerca.text
        tuerca1= str(round(float(tuerca) * 0.35,2)) if tuerca else "0.0"
        tuerca2= tuerca1 + "0"  
        self.ids.label_tuerca.text= tuerca2

        
        
      
    #self.ids.input_tornillo.text= self.ids.label_tornillo.text




    def press_on(self):
        self.ids.input_tornillo.text= self.ids.label_tornillo.text
        #self.ids.my_label.text= "You Pressed the Button"
        #self.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= self.var2
    def press_off(self):
        self.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= self.var1
        

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass

class FourthWindow(Screen):
    def message(self):
        pass
      
    def resetcampos (self):
        #self.window_manager.get_screen("Contact").ids.nombre.text = ""  - Enter another class
        self.ids.nombre.text = ""
        self.ids.telefono.text = ""
        self.ids.correo.text = ""
        self.ids.asunto.text = ""
        self.ids.mensaje.text = ""


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Kv.Main

```
<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            rows:3
            
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: 65

            Spinner:

                id: spinner_id
                text: "Menu"
                values: ["Catalogue","Buy","Payment Methods", "Contact"]
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id.text)
                on_text: window_manager.current = self.text  # uses an id defined in the WindowManager section
                #on_text: root.manager.current= "second" - Just work in Screens

        

            Image:
                source: 'images/ferrepluslogo2.png'
             

            Button:
                text:"Buy"

    

        WindowManager:
            id: window_manager
            FirstWindow:
            SecondWindow:
            ThirdWindow:
            FourthWindow:  
    
<FirstWindow>:
    name: "Catalogue"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size: root.width, root.height
        size_hint_y: .55
        GridLayout:
            size:(root.width, root.height)
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            cols:4
            height: self.minimum_height

            Label:
                text: "Items"
                #font_size: 25
            Label:
                text: "Number"
            Label:
                text: "Price"
            Label:
                text: "Add to Cart"

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .80
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': .11}
        do_scroll_x: True
        do_scroll_y: True
        GridLayout:
            size:root.width, root.height
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            cols:4
            #height: self.minimum_height
        

            #Label:
            #    text: "Items"
                #font_size: 25
            #Label:
            #    text: "Number"
            #Label:
            #    text: "Price"
            #Label:
            #    text: "Add to Cart"
            Label:
                text: "Tornillos"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                Image:
                    id: image_tornillos
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                    width: 60
                    height: 80
                    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                    source: "images/tornillo.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y+10
            TextInput: 
                id: input_tornillo
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                multiline: True
                on_text: root.list_tornillo()
                
                #size_hint: (1, .15)
                

            Label:
                id: label_tornillo
                text: "0.0"
                #text: root.ids.input_tornillo.text*2
                
                
                           
            
            Button:
                id: shopping1
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on() 
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart1.source= root.var1 
                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart1
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: root.var1
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
            

            #------------------------
            
            Label:
                text: "Andamios"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                Image:
                    id: image_andamios
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                    width: 60
                    height: 80
                    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                    source: "images/Andamios.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y   
                
            TextInput: 
                id: input_andamio
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)
                on_text: root.list_andamio()

            Label:
                id: label_andamio
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping2
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on()
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart2.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart2.source= root.var1 

                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart2
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: "images/shoppingcart.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y        
            #-----------------------------------------------------------
            #Image:
            #    id: image_viguetas
            #    allow_stretch: True
            #    keep_ratio: True
            #    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
            #    width: 40
            #    height: 60
            #    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
            #    source: "images/viguetas.jpg"
            #    center_x: self.parent.center_x
            #    center_y: self.parent.center_y             
            Label:
                text: "Viguetas"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "images/viguetas.jpg"
        
            TextInput: 
                id: input_vigueta
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)
                on_text: root.list_vigueta()

            Label:
                id: label_vigueta
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping3
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on()
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart3.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart3.source= root.var1 

                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart3
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: "images/shoppingcart.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
            #------------------------------------------------------------
            #Image:
            #    id: image_pernos
            #    allow_stretch: True
            #    keep_ratio: True
            #    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
            #    width: 40
            #    height: 60
            #    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
            #    source: "images/pernos.png"
            #    center_x: self.parent.center_x
            #    center_y: self.parent.center_y             
            Label:
                text: "Pernos"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:                       
                        pos: self.center_x-39, self.center_y-21
                        #pos: self.pos
                        size: 77,50
                        source: "images/pernos.png"
            
            TextInput: 
                id: input_perno
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)
                on_text: root.list_perno()

            Label:
                text: "0.0"
                id: label_perno
            
            Button:
                id: shopping4
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on()
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart4.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart4.source= root.var1 

                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart4
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: "images/shoppingcart.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y

            #------------------------------------------------------------
                
            Label:
                text: "Tuercas"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:                       
                        pos: self.center_x-39, self.center_y-21
                        #pos: self.pos
                        size: 77,50
                        source: "images/tuercas.png"
            
            TextInput: 
                id: input_tuerca
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)
                on_text: root.list_tuerca()

            Label:
                id: label_tuerca
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping5
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on()
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart5.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart5.source= root.var1 

                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart5
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: "images/shoppingcart.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y

            #----------------------------------------------
            Label:
                text: "Tejas"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:                       
                        pos: self.center_x-39, self.center_y-21
                        #pos: self.pos
                        size: 77,50
                        source: "images/Teja.png"
            
            TextInput: 
                id: input_teja
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)

            Label:
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping6
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on()
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart6.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart6.source= root.var1 

                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart6
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: "images/shoppingcart.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y

             #----------------------------------------------
            Label:
                text: "Tableros"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:                       
                        pos: self.center_x-39, self.center_y-21
                        #pos: self.pos
                        size: 77,50
                        source: "images/tableros.png"
            
            TextInput: 
                id: input_tablero
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                #size_hint: (1, .15)

            Label:
                text: "0.0"
            
            Button:
                id: shopping7
                #text: "Hello"
                #font_size: 32
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                size_hint: .25,.30
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                #on_press: root.press_on()
                #on_release: root.press_off()
                on_press: root.ids.Shoppingcart7.source= root.var2 
                on_release: root.ids.Shoppingcart7.source= root.var1 

                Image:
                    id: Shoppingcart7
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.5,0.5
                    width: 60
                    height: 60
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                    source: "images/shoppingcart.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y










            #-------------------------------------------

            Button:
                text:""
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
            Button:
                text:""
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
            Button:
                text:""
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
            Button:
                text:""
                background_color: 0,0,0,0

            #------------------------------------------------------------
        
<RV>:
 
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .73
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': .11}
        do_scroll_x: True
        do_scroll_y: True
        GridLayout:
            size:(root.width, root.height)
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            cols:2
            height: self.minimum_height

            Button:
                text:"las"
            Button:
                text:"cosas"
            Button:
                text:"de la vida"
            Button:
                text:"las"
            Button:
                text:"cosas"
            Button:
                text:"de la vida"

        
        
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "Buy"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Buy Screen"
            font_size: 32

       

<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "Payment Methods"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Payment Methods Screen"
            font_size: 32


<FourthWindow>:
    name: "Contact"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        #pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        #size: root.width, root.height
        #size_hint_y: .55
        Label:
            id:Escribir
            text:"     Escríbenos:"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            size: root.width, root.height
            size_hint_y: .55
            font_size: 20
            bold: True
            #----
            #text_size: self.size
            #valign: 'center'
            #halign: 'left'
     
    
        GridLayout:
            #padding: 15
            cols:2           
            #size_hint: None,None
            #height: 65
            #size_hint: .7,1
            
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 0.5,1
                orientation:"vertical"
                Label:
                    text:"Nombre:"
                            
                Label:              
                    text:"Telefono:"
                

                Label:                
                    text:"Email:"         

                Label:                
                    text:"Asunto:"
            BoxLayout:
                padding: [0,0,10,0] #left, top, right, bottom
                orientation:"vertical"
                TextInput:
                    text: ""
                    id: nombre

                TextInput:
                    text: ""
                    id: telefono

                TextInput:
                    text: ""
                    id:correo

                TextInput:
                    text: ""
                    id: asunto

            

            
        GridLayout:
            cols:2 
            #size_hint: .7,1      
            Label:                
                text:"Mensaje:"
                size_hint: .5,1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                padding: [0,0,10,0]
                TextInput:
                    id:mensaje
                    

            
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"

            Label:
                text: ""
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                size: root.width, root.height
                size_hint_y: .55

            GridLayout:
                cols:3
                Label:
                    text: ""
                Button:
                    text:"Enviar Mensaje"
                    on_press: root.message()
                    on_press: Factory.MyPopup().open()
                Label:
                    text: ""
            Label:
                text:""
            Label:
                text: "  Contacto:"
                font_size: 20
                bold: True
                #pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                #size: root.width, root.height
                #size_hint_y: .55
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                #size_hint: .3,1 
                Label:                
                    text:"                               Telefono:"
                    size_hint: .2,1 

                Label:                
                    text:"Email:"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                padding: [0,0,90,0]
                        
                Label:                
                    text:"198797978"
                    
                Label:                
                    text:"washington@hotmail.com"

            Label:
                text: ""

            Label:
                text: ""
        

#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<MyPopup@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 0.8,0.2
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
    title: "Atención"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: "Su mensaje fue enviado exitosamente"
            font_size: 15
        Button:
            text:"Cerrar"
            font_size: 15
            on_release: root.dismiss()
            on_press: main.FourthWindow.resetcampos()
            #on_press: window_manager.resetcampos()
```

Comment: It depends on how your `FourthWindow` is connected to the GUI.

Comment: I just updated my code, can U check it  pls again?  My fourthWindow is inside the MyLayout..  But the Popup is out of the fourthwindow and It's only called for a function

Comment: I was trying in these 2 ways in the Button "Cerrar" and It doesn´t work: 
#on_press: main.FourthWindow.resetcampos()
#on_press: window_manager.resetcampos()

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete and not runnable. Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: HI just sent the whole code this time, pls can U check it?

Comment: You posted code is to large to be a minimal one. However it seems that the following may be what you're looking for : `on_press: app.root.ids.window_manager.get_screen("Contact").resetcampos()`

Comment: Can u check this pls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880407/using-a-cyclefor-for-creating-several-onelinelistitem-from-a-list-in-kivymd